# MariaDB won't start on Ubuntu: Can't lock aria control file

Tags: 14.04, mariadb

I run into this error occassionaly after a scheduled backup. Upon a 
service mysql restart ... it fails to come up.

Attempting a manual start, gives me this.

```
mysqld 
161125  7:40:48 [ERROR] mysqld: Can't lock aria control file '/var/lib/mysql/aria_log_control' for exclusive use, error: 11. Will retry for 30 seconds 
161125  7:40:49 [Note] InnoDB: Using mutexes to ref count buffer pool pages 
161125  7:40:49 [Note] InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled 
161125  7:40:49 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins 
161125  7:40:49 [Note] InnoDB: Memory barrier is not used 
161125  7:40:49 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.8 
161125  7:40:49 [Note] InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO 
161125  7:40:49 [Note] InnoDB: Using CPU crc32 instructions 
161125  7:40:49 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 64.0M 
161125  7:40:49 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool 
161125  7:40:49 [Note] InnoDB: Highest supported file format is Barracuda. 
161125  7:40:49 [Note] InnoDB: 128 rollback segment(s) are active. 
161125  7:40:49 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for urge to start 
161125  7:40:49 [Note] InnoDB:  Percona XtraDB (http://www.percona.com) 5.6.22-72.0 started; log sequence number 13113858453 
161125  7:40:49 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled. 
161125  7:40:49 [ERROR] mysqld: File '/var/log/mysql/mariadb-bin.009076' not found (Errcode: 2 "No such file or directory") 
161125  7:40:49 [ERROR] Failed to open log    (file '/var/log/mysql/mariadb-bin.009076', errno 2) 
161125  7:40:49 [ERROR] Could not open log file 
161125  7:40:49 [ERROR] Can't init tc log 
161125  7:40:49 [ERROR] Aborting
161125  7:40:49 [Note] InnoDB: FTS optimize thread exiting. 
161125  7:40:49 [Note] InnoDB: Starting shutdown... 
161125  7:40:51 [Note] InnoDB: Shutdown completed; log sequence number 13113858463
161125  7:40:51 [Note] mysqld: Shutdown complete
```

I have tried deleting the aria_log_control file and starting again, but the same error occurs.

mysqld_safe isn't doing it either.

```
 mysqld_safe 
161206 12:36:14 mysqld_safe Logging to syslog. 
161206 12:36:14 mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /var/lib/mysql 
161206 12:36:16 mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid ended 
root@server:/var/lib/mysql# mysql ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2 "No such file or directory")
```

What else should I look at?

Thanks!

Comment: Thank you for the edit, @heynnema!  I tried 4 times to get that right!

Comment: You're welcome. The trick is the `<pre>` and `</pre>` tags. Then just minor touchup to fix some formatting problems.

Comment: The <pre> and </pre> doesn't work in comments. Edit your original question to include your new output, include the pre tags. Delete the above comment after.

Comment: Deleting both ib_logfile0 and ib_logfile1 got me past the first error.

Comment: I still get the error about missing /var/log/mysq/mariadb-bin.<serial number>

Answer (score 4):

After deleting the aria_log* files and the ib_logfile* files, I turned off binary logging per http://community.rtcamp.com/t/mariadb-bin-log-eat-my-disk-space/4278/4

Mysql started ...