# Not able to start mysql in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: server, mysql, services, mariadb

I'm using Ubuntu 16.04 and Mysql was running. But the database is crashed and I was trying to recover it. After that I'm not to start Mysql service, I'm facing the below issue.

```
Starting mysql (via systemctl): mysql.serviceJob for mysql.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status mysql.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details

*systemctl status mysql.service*

May 02 17:24:15 controller mysqld[1310]: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(gsignal+0x38)[0x7f3ee5af0428]
May 02 17:24:15 controller mysqld[1310]: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(abort+0x16a)[0x7f3ee5af202a]
May 02 17:24:15 controller mysqld[1310]: /usr/sbin/mysqld[0xaac043]
May 02 17:24:15 controller mysqld[1310]: /usr/sbin/mysqld[0xaad584]
May 02 17:24:15 controller mysqld[1310]: /usr/sbin/mysqld[0xaae456]
May 02 17:24:15 controller mysqld[1310]: /usr/sbin/mysqld[0xaa0d4f]


*error.log* 

170502 16:58:03 [ERROR] mysqld: Can't lock aria control file '/var/lib/mysql/aria_log_control' for exclusive use, error: 11. Will retry for 30 seconds 
170502 16:58:07 [Note] InnoDB: Using mutexes to ref count buffer pool pages 
170502 16:58:07 [Note] InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled 
170502 16:58:07 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins 
170502 16:58:07 [Note] InnoDB: GCC builtin __atomic_thread_fence() is used for memory barrier 
170502 16:58:07 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.8 
170502 16:58:07 [Note] InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO 
170502 16:58:07 [Note] InnoDB: Not using CPU crc32 instructions 
170502 16:58:07 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 128.0M 170502 16:58:07 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool 170502 16:58:07 [Note] InnoDB: Highest supported file format is Barracuda. 170502 16:58:07 [Note] InnoDB: 128 rollback segment(s) are active. 
170502 16:58:07 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start 
170502 16:58:07 [Note] InnoDB: Percona XtraDB  5.6.34-79.1 started; log sequence number 236462075 
170502 16:58:07 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled. 
170502 16:58:08 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: ready for connections. 
Version: '10.0.29-MariaDB-0ubuntu0.16.04.1' 
socket: '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' 
port: 0 
Ubuntu 16.04 2017-05-02 16:58:08 7fc4adffa700 
InnoDB: Assertion failure in thread 140482709530368 in file trx0purge.cc line 703 
InnoDB: Failing assertion: purge_sys->iter.trx_no <= purge_sys->rseg->last_trx_no 
InnoDB: We intentionally generate a memory trap. 
InnoDB: Submit a detailed bug report to http://bugs.mysql.com. 
InnoDB: If you get repeated assertion failures or crashes, even 
InnoDB: immediately after the mysqld startup, there may be 
InnoDB: corruption in the InnoDB tablespace. Please refer to InnoDB InnoDB: about forcing recovery. 

170502 16:58:08 [ERROR] mysqld got signal 6 ; This could be because you hit a bug. It is also possible that this binary or one of the libraries it was linked against is corrupt, improperly built, or misconfigured. This error can also be caused by malfunctioning hardware.

We will try our best to scrape up some info that will hopefully help
diagnose the problem, but since we have already crashed,
something is definitely wrong and this may fail.

Server version: 10.0.29-MariaDB-0ubuntu0.16.04.1
key_buffer_size=16777216
read_buffer_size=131072
max_used_connections=0
max_threads=4098
thread_count=0
It is possible that mysqld could use up to
key_buffer_size + (read_buffer_size + sort_buffer_size)*max_threads = 9014835 K  bytes of memory
Hope that's ok; if not, decrease some variables in the equation.

Thread pointer: 0x0
Attempting backtrace. You can use the following information to find out
where mysqld died. If you see no messages after this, something went
terribly wrong...
stack_bottom = 0x0 thread_stack 0x30000
/usr/sbin/mysqld(my_print_stacktrace+0x3d)[0xc1b2cd]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(handle_fatal_signal+0x3bf)[0x74366f]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0(+0x11390)[0x7fc4ce868390]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(gsignal+0x38)[0x7fc4cde38428]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(abort+0x16a)[0x7fc4cde3a02a]
/usr/sbin/mysqld[0xaac043]
/usr/sbin/mysqld[0xaad584]
/usr/sbin/mysqld[0xaae456]
/usr/sbin/mysqld[0xaa0d4f]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0(+0x76ba)[0x7fc4ce85e6ba]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(clone+0x6d)[0x7fc4cdf0982d]
The manual page a contains
information that should help you find out what is causing the crash.
```

Please someone help me to start mysql service and to recover the DB.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: remove it and reinstall it.

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/857713/mariadb-wont-start-on-ubuntu-cant-lock-aria-control-file

Comment: @Rinzwind I wanted to vote along with you but you could comment on how MariaDB duplicate candidate is the same as MySQL in this question.